# Test passing in isolation but failing when running suite - RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Really strange problem here. When I run my test in isolation each of my 3 tests pass. but, if I run the context they each fail but intermittently pass. The test are running into each other but I don't know where or how. Here are the faulty tests.

```
    context "creating an account" do
    let!(:user) { login_user }
    let!(:plan) { create(:plan, :public, :unlimited, name: "Private Eye") }

    before do
      allow_any_instance_of(Gabba::Gabba).to receive_messages(event: true)
    end

    it "can create a new account" do
      visit new_account_path

      fill_in :account_name, with: "New Account"

      find("#stripe_card_token").set("tok_3HUgs79WEx47q9")

      VCR.use_cassette("stripe/create_customer_paid_plan") do
        choose("plan_id_2")
        fill_in :card_number, with: "4242424242424242"
        select "12", from: :date_month
        select Date.current.year, from: :date_year

        expect { click_button "Complete Project Setup" }
          .to change(Account, :count).by(1)
          .and change(user.reload.accounts, :count).by(1)
      end

      account = Account.find_by(name: "New Account")

      expect(current_path).to eq(snitches_path)
      expect(account.name).to eq("New Account")
      expect(account.cc_last4).to eq("4242")
      expect(account.cc_expiration_year).to eq(2016)
      expect(account.cc_expiration_month).to eq(12)
    end

    it "for a paid plan without a credit card" do
      visit new_account_path

      choose("plan_id_2")
      fill_in :account_name, with: "My New Account"

      expect { click_button "Complete Project Setup" }
        .not_to change(Account, :count)

      expect(page).to have_content("Oops. You need to enter a credit card to sign up for a paid plan.")
    end

    it "switches user to the new account upon creation" do
      visit new_account_path

      find("#stripe_card_token").set("tok_3HUgs79WEx47q9")

      VCR.use_cassette("stripe/create_customer_paid_plan") do
        choose("plan_id_2")
        fill_in :account_name, with: "My New Account"
        fill_in :card_number, with: "4242424242424242"
        select "12", from: :date_month
        select Date.current.year, from: :date_year

        click_button "Complete Project Setup"
      end

      expect(current_path).to eq(snitches_path)
      expect(page).to have_content("My New Account")
      expect(Account.find_by(id: current_account).name).to eq("My New Account")
    end
  end
```

Maybe you will see something right off the bat but I can't seem to find the problem. If anybody has ideas why this would be happening I would love it! Thank you.

Just to be clear. If I run any of these in isolation they each pass but fail if I run the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bisect command in order to identify the execution order that makes the test fail.

The command is:

```
rspec --bisect
```

It returns something like this:

```
The minimal reproduction command is:
  rspec ./spec/features/my_amazing_feature_spec.rb[1:1]
```

So you can use it to fix your code and confirm your fix.